# How can I submit a form only when certain condition is true, regardless of how many times the condition changes between false and true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Evening!

Sorry for my english.

I'm ultra new in Js and I'm trying to accomplish the following;

I have a form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXSMA.png)

And here is a piece of the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add checked class to the div.checkbox
    $("#checkbox").click(function () { 
        $("#checkbox").toggleClass("checked");
    });
    // Submit if checkbox has been "checked"
    $("#bttnEnviar").click(function () { 
        if ($("#checkbox").hasClass("checked") == false) {
            $("#bttnEnviar").submit(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
        else{
            $("#bttnEnviar").unbind("submit");
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
*{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
.politicaP{
        margin: 16px 0;
        /*Flex*/
        display: flex;
    }
    /* Properties and values for the div.checkbox*/
.checkbox{
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
.textoPolitica{
        width: 90%;
    }
.textoPolitica :first-child{
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
.textoPolitica a{
        display: inline;
    }
.requestInfo button{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*Add bg-color to simulate selected*/
.checked{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="politicaP">
    <div id="checkbox" class="checkbox"></div> <!-- This is my checkbox -->
    <div class="textoPolitica">
        <p>Acepto la <a href="politica">Politica de Privacidad</a>.</p>
        <p>Tus datos no serán guardados, cedidos o comunicados, ni por      nosotros ni por terceras personas</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="bttnEnviar" type="submit" class="bttnFormulario">Enviar</button>
```

I can't use an input type="checkbox" because I can't apply styles to it, that is why I have created my own checkbox.

What I want is that each time I (the user) press the "Enviar" button, a condition runs and evaluates if the div.checkbox has the class checked, if it has it, then the button can send the information, if not, it doesn't do anything.

This needs to be evaluated always, as for example if I click on div.checkbox but then I want to click again (unchecking the div), the button can not send the information once I press it, and only submit the information, regardless no matter on how many times I check and uncheck the div.checkbox, only when the div.checkbox has the class checked on it.

I don't know if that is unclear, truly sorry again, english is not my matern language and Js is new to me

Comment: Your code is a bit overly complex but it appears to do what you want: when the "Enviar" button is pressed, decide whether the checkbox is checked. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem was (Rush.2707 replied with the solution to my headache) that if I would press the "Enviar" button, preventDefault() would do its magic and it continued to do it even after div.checkbox was checked.  So, the information would never be send.The problem was (Rush.2707 replied with the solution to my headache) that if I would press the "Enviar" button, preventDefault() would do its magic and it continued to do it even after div.checkbox was checked.  So, the information would never be send.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add checked class to the div.checkbox
    $("#checkbox").click(function () { 
        $("#checkbox").toggleClass("checked");
    });
    // Submit if checkbox has been "checked"
    $("#bttnEnviar").click(function (e) { 
        if ($("#checkbox").hasClass("checked") == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else{
          console.log('runnig');
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
*{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
.politicaP{
        margin: 16px 0;
        /*Flex*/
        display: flex;
    }
    /* Properties and values for the div.checkbox*/
.checkbox{
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        margin-right: 6px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
.textoPolitica{
        width: 90%;
    }
.textoPolitica :first-child{
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
.textoPolitica a{
        display: inline;
    }
.requestInfo button{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*Add bg-color to simulate selected*/
.checked{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="politicaP">
    <div id="checkbox" class="checkbox"></div> <!-- This is my checkbox -->
    <div class="textoPolitica">
        <p>Acepto la <a href="politica">Politica de Privacidad</a>.</p>
        <p>Tus datos no serán guardados, cedidos o comunicados, ni por      nosotros ni por terceras personas</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="bttnEnviar" type="submit" class="bttnFormulario">Enviar</button>
```

According to whatever written in question i think this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, that was the answer, thank you very much, now I understand a bit more of Js, again, thanks.